# ANTLR position specific Tokens

Tags: token, antlr4

We want to ANTLR grammar where "0" in first position treated differently compared with other position.

**Sample Input**

```
0 Test
World 0
```

Is there anyway to identify position or context specific Token?

Currently we are writing code to change the Token type.

**Grammar**

```
// Define a grammar called Hello
grammar Hello;

r : (r2 | r1)+ ;

r2 : 'World' Num ;
r1 : keyZero 'Test';

keyZero : {_input.LT(1).getCharPositionInLine() == 0}? Num ;
Num : [0-9]+ ;

Ws : [ ] -> skip;
Eol : [\r\n]->skip;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be handled in the lexer:

```
grammar Hello;

r  : (r2 | r1)+ EOF;   
r2 : 'World' NUM ;
r1 : KEY_ZERO 'Test';

KEY_ZERO : {getCharPositionInLine() == 0}? [0-9]+;
NUM      : [0-9]+;
SPACE    : [ \r\n] -> skip;
```

Comment: It is working.. thanks Bart. We have modify grammar.. just remove _input and it worked for us.